# Connect to FTP with PHP with a password that has @

Tags: php, ftp, special-characters

I have the following problem:

I need connect to FTP and read one CSV file. The main problem it's password has @, $, %... How can I connect with especials characters? I tried the following ways to connect:

FILE OPEN

```
$filename = 'ftp://user:p@s($word@ftp.myftp.url/file.csv'; 
$handle = fopen($filename, "r") or die("Error");
```

FTP LOGIN

```
$ftp_server = "ftp.myftp.url/file.csv";
$ftp_user = "user";
$ftp_pass = "p@s($word";
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");
$login_result = ftp_login($ftp_server, $ftp_user, $ftp_pass) or die("Could not connect to 2");
$data = file_get_contents('ftp.myftp.url/file.csv');
```

Thanks for all!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two distinct problems with your two pieces of code.

---

> FILE OPEN
>
> ```
> $filename = 'ftp://user:p@s($word@ftp.myftp.url/file.csv'; 
> $handle = fopen($filename, "r") or die("Error");
> ```

Here, the problem is the `@`, as you have correctly guessed, as it has a meaning in the [URL syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) (as a separator between credentials and hostname).

You have to [URL-encode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) the `@` to `%40`:

```
$filename = 'ftp://user:p%40s($word@ftp.myftp.url/file.csv';
```

You mentioned that the actual password also has `%`. That has to be [URL-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Percent_character) to `%25`.

---

> FTP LOGIN
>
> ```
> $ftp_server = "ftp.myftp.url/file.csv";
> $ftp_user = "user";
> $ftp_pass = "p@s($word";
> $conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");
> $login_result = ftp_login($ftp_server, $ftp_user, $ftp_pass) or die("Could not connect to 2");
> ```

Here, the problem is not `@`, as no URL is involved (neither `%` would be a problem). Here, the problem is the `$`, as you are [using double-quotes, so `$word` is replaced with a value of (probably undefined) variable `word`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double), effectively making the password be `p@s(` only.

Use [single quotes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single) to avoid the `$` being interpreted as a variable:

```
 $ftp_pass = 'p@s($word';
```

Or escape the `$` with `\`:

```
 $ftp_pass = "p@s(\$word";
```

Answer (score -1):

You should replace hexadecimal value for @(at) char. Try this,

`@ -> %40,
 $ -> %24`

`$ftp_pass = "p%40s(%24word";`

Comment: The `@` is not a problem in the `$ftp_pass`. And there are better ways to deal with the `$` than URL-encoding it.